# Implicit differentiation: $\ln(1+xy) = xy$

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

$\ln(1+xy) = xy$

When I try to implicitly differentiate this I get

$\frac{1}{1+xy}(y + xy')$ = (y + xy')

At which point the $(y + xy')$ terms cancel out, leaving no $y'$ to solve for.

However, the answer to this is $-\frac{y}{x}$... How do you get this?

Comment: What makes you think you can cancel the $y+xy'$ terms?

Comment: @user1337 Well it is an equation right...?

Comment: what if $y+xy'=0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only cancel the $y+xy'$ terms if that is not equal to zero, otherwise you're dividing by zero. Assuming that is not equal to zero gets you 
$$
\frac{1}{1+xy} = 1
$$
so
$1+xy=1$, or $xy=0$, which gives you $\log 1=0$ in the original equation. So the solution is based on the notion that for the equation to be non-trivial, $y+xy'=0$.

Incidentally, based on the hint in abel's post, I tried solving the differential equation, and I got
$$
{dy \over y} = -{dx \over x}
$$
which yields
$$
\ln y = -\ln x + c \Rightarrow y=k/x.
$$
But, as abel states, the only real solution for the original equation is $k=0$. [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+ln%281%2Ba%29%3Da) gives a useful graph.

Answer (score 4):

the only real solution for $\ln(1 + u) = u$ is $u = 0.$  so your equation implies $xy = 0,$ which in turn gives $y = 0$ identically. hence $\frac{dy}{dx}  = 0.$

Comment: This is a very useful contribution.

Comment: This is how I saw the problem, too.